# How to pass list of string in when condition of role in Ansible?

Tags: loops, server, ansible, conditional-statements

I have been trying to use a `when` condition to filter out the inventory to be run in a specific role in Ansible.
I have a list of pattern that should match the `instance_name`, given in inventory.

I tried:

```yaml
roles:
  - role: DEMO_CHECK
    when: instance_name is match(item)
    loop: "{{ include_list }}"
    vars:
      include_list: 
        - ABC.*XYZ
        - PQR.*TST
```

But I am getting the error:

> 'item' is undefined

I also tried, unsuccessfully, with moustaches around `item`, i.e.:

- `instance_name is match( "{{ item }}" )`
- `instance_name is match({{ item }})`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a role, used in `roles` simply cannot be looped.

This can be tested with a simple role:
*demo_role/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: foo
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - role: demo_role
      loop:
        - foo
        - bar
```

That yields an unique message:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [demo_role : debug] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: foo

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0
```

---

But why isn't Ansible complaining about the `loop` that should be an invalid attribute of a role, then? It is simple, it is considered as a variable that will be available to all the tasks of this role.

We can demonstrate it by modifying *demo_role/tasks/main.yml*:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ loop }}"
```

And now our playbook yields:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [demo_role : debug] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - foo
  - bar

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0
```

---

Now, to achieve what you want, you will have to use an [`include_role` task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#including-roles-dynamic-reuse) instead, by modifying your playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: demo_role
      loop: "{{ include_list }}"
      when: instance_name is match(item)
      vars:
        include_list:
          - ABC.*XYZ
          - PQR.*TST
        instance_name: ABC...XYZ
```

Which yield the expected:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [include_role : demo_role] ******************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=PQR.*TST) 

TASK [demo_role : debug] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: foo

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0
```